# How to use scanf in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, scanf

I'm trying to make something like the following:

```
x = scanf(stdin);
```

But it has to be in OCaml, I've been reading but I can't seem to find a proper way to do this, what I'm doing is a card game and in the beginning I want to ask the user of the game, through the terminal, the amount of players that are going to play and that's why I need to scan from standard in. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you read `http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a simple task, scanf is probably overkill. You might want to use `read_int` to get started.

```
# read_int ();;
17
- : int = 17
```

(The second line here is typed by the user, i.e., me.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify `stdin`, do something like:

```
print_string "Enter number of players: ";
let p = scanf "%d" (fun x:int -> x) in
  print_int p;
  print_newline()
```